# Android AutoParcel crashes at Parcel.writeValue() condition instanceof IBinder

Tags: android, parcel

Using [AutoParcel](https://github.com/frankiesardo/auto-parcel) 0.3.1 to implement Parcelable for my domain model 'User' (simple POJO)

```
class User {
    private String firstName;
    private Date lastSeen;
    private Image profileImage;

    ... other primitive variables
}

class Image {
    private Date createdDate;
    private int id;
    private String imageUrl;
}

@AutoParcel
public abstract class UserParcel implements Parcelable {

public abstract User getUser();

public static UserParcel create(User user) {
    return new AutoParcel_UserParcel(user);
}
```

This is my error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value User{...
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1343)
at com.mypackage.parcels.AutoParcel_UserParce.writeToParcel(AutoParcel_UserParcel.java:69)
at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1363)
```

Looking at logs the crash occurs at Parcel class (line writeStrongBinder):

```
public final void writeValue(Object v) {

   ...

   else if (v instanceof IBinder) {       
      writeInt(VAL_IBINDER);
      writeStrongBinder((IBinder) v);
   }
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Thank you in advance :)